# Creating a list in json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I want to display a "pretty" format of JSON api. I am using Active Model Serializers for most part. I learned that I can "prettify" my JSON display using `JSON.pretty_generate()` method.

I have tested it using a dummy data and it worked on browser:

```
def index
 #@users = User.all
 my_object = { :array => [1, 2, 3, { :sample => "hash"} ], :foo => "bar" }
 render json: JSON.pretty_generate(my_object)
end
```

**localhost:**

```
#=> {
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    {
      "sample": "hash"
    }
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

My goal is to display a list of user information on index. Right now it does not have the indentation and newline... well, it does not look pretty:

**User controller:**

```
def index
     @users = User.all     
     render json: @users, each_serializer: UserSerializer, adapter: :json
UserSerializer)
   end
```

**localhost:**

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"username":"Iggy1","items":[{"id":1,"list_id":1,"name":"Wash dishes","completed":true},{"id":7,"list_id":1,"name":"Finish this assignment","completed":false}],"lists":[{"id":1,"name":"Important!","user_id":1,"permission":"private"},{"id":8,"name":"Bloc's obligatory list number two","user_id":1,"permission":"private"},{"id":14,"name":"Mandatory list one","user_id":1,"permission":"private"},{"id":15,"name":null,"use...
```

After much trial and error, I figured out that I need to have @users to be a list of json. Proof - when I run this:

**User Controller:**

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: JSON.pretty_generate(@users), each_serializer: UserSerializer
end
```

**localhost *(shows error msg)***

`#=> only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed`

How can I apply `JSON.pretty_generate()` on `User.all` on user controller index?

Comment: I think only render render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert hash to json:

```
JSON.pretty_generate(@users.to_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert first `@users` with `to_json`:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: JSON.pretty_generate(@users.to_json), each_serializer: UserSerializer
end
```

Comment: Still shows the same error: "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed" using code above. If I use @users.to_a, it shows [
  "#<User:0x007fd749651058>",
  "#<User:0x007fd749650f18>",
  "#<User:0x007fd749650dd8>",
  "#<User:0x007fd749650c98>",
  "#<User:0x007fd749650b58>",
  "#<User:0x007fd749650a18>",
  "#<User:0x007fd7496508d8>",
  "#<User:0x007fd749650798>"
]

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your object in `json` like :

```
   render json: JSON.pretty_generate(@users.as_json), each_serializer: UserSerializer
```

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: You're right! I totally forgot the error says "...JSOn objects or arrays". Somehow I am blanking out on arrays. Thanks for the reminder!